# What's the difference between 防止法 and 禁止法?

Tags: word-choice, law

As the title says. I was trying to search for the Japanese name of the Minor Drinking Prohibition Act but when I couldn't find anything, I just took a shot and typed in 未成年者飲酒防止法. By luck, I managed to get the law, but saw the only difference was that 防止法 was 禁止法。

From my understanding, both of these seem to mean "law prohibiting something" but I was wondering if there was any functional, subtle difference between the two and how you know which one should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's 禁止法, not 防止法. 防止 means prevention. You say 防止策 or 防止対策 (ways to prevent).